# How to find the best affine approximation to $F^{-1}$ near $(1,1)$, where $F(x,y)=(x^3+2xy+y^2, x^2+y)$?

Tags: calculus

I proved that $F(x,y)=(x^3+2xy+y^2,x^2+y)$ is locally invertible at $(1,1)$. But how can we find inverse? And best affine approximation to the INVERSE of $f$ near $(1,1)$?

I cant find inverse therefore affine approximation.

Comment: How did you prove that $F$ is locally invertible?

Comment: And how do you know that this guarantees that an inverse exists?

Comment: $D(F(x))$ it is easy use Jacobian

Comment: $D(F(x,y))\neq 0$

Comment: I didn’t ask you how you computed the differential. I asked you how the condition $DF\ne0$ lets you know that an inverse exists.

Comment: this is theorem if $D(F(x,y))\neq 0$ Jacobian determinant is nonzero so it is invertible hence locally invertible

Comment: Use asked many questions @amd if you know help if you dont know ok u r welcome

Comment: There’s more to that theorem. What does it say about the differentials of $F$ and its inverse?

Comment: I know how to do it. Moreover I also know that the approximation to $F^{-1}$ can be found without knowing $F^{-1}$ itself, by using the *all* of the theorem that you appear to be using. I’m trying to help you to realize that you probably already know how to do it, too. Evidently, you’re far too impatient for the Socratic method and simply want someone to feed you the answer.

Comment: Use the fact that $D(F^{-1})=D^{-1}(F)$ and will know the partial derivates. So, integrating ends